# Theano/lasagne: ValueError: mismatch: got 10 values to set 0 parameters

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

I've trained a neural network in theano/lasagne and saved the network parameters with this piece of code:

```
np.savez('model.npz', *lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(network))
```

Now I want to load the model and set the parameters to the network so I can test if it is working correctly. I'm loading the parameters with this piece of code:

```
with np.load('model.npz') as f:
        param_values = [f['arr_%d' % i] for i in range(len(f.files))]
```

Then I try to set the parameters of the network to the loaded parameters like this:

```
lasagne.layers.set_all_param_values(self._output_layer, param_values, allow_input_downcast=True)
```

But then I get this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snake_player.py", line 406, in <module>
    player = SnakePlayer()
  File "snake_player.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.loadModel()
  File "snake_player.py", line 328, in loadModel
    lasagne.layers.set_all_param_values(self._output_layer, param_values, allow_input_downcast=True, trainable=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers\helper.py", line 446, in set_all_param_values
    (len(values), len(params)))
ValueError: mismatch: got 10 values to set 0 parameters
```

However when I get all the parameters in the network and look at the length, there are 10 parameters.

```
x = lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(self._output_layer)
len(x) # 10
```

So the amount of parameters is the same and somehow I still get this error. Any idea why? Am I overlooking something?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This won't happen if you call `set_all_param_values` without `allow_input_downcast=True` flag.